# Using Alamofire for curl -u

Tags: curl, alamofire

I am using alamofire for this curl -

```
curl https://yoursite.desk.com/api/v2/customers \
-u email:password \
-X POST \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe"}'
```

it works with curl but not alamofire when i pass user and password -

```
    Alamofire.request(.POST, API_END_POINT, parameters: parameter)
        .authenticate(user: user, password: password)
        .responseJSON(options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) {
            (request, response, data, error) in
            print(error)
            print(data)
    }
```

I always got `Unauthenticated` error . Seemingly it never verify user and password.